# Magento consistent product URLs

Tags: php, url, magento

Magento seems to have a number of different formats that work for product URLs, including:

```
/catalog/product/view/id/123/s/my-product-slug/
/my-product-slug/
/top-category/sub-category/my-product-slug/
etc...
```

I want to just use one of these, always, which is the 3rd one, concatenating all parent category slugs together before the product slug. Is there a way to configure Magento to only use one of these formats?

Using methods like `getProductUrl()` seems to return different results depending on what page/context you're on, can anyone tell me why this is?

And in general does anyone know of any documentation or blog posts, etc., that might help me understand routing in Magento a little better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clockworkgeek was pretty close and led me to my answer...

I tried using `$product->setCategoryId()` and was finding that `$product->getCategoryId()` wasn't returning anything and that the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::getUrl` method depends on the `getCategoryId` method on the product model to figure out a product's URL. Turns out `getCategoryId` is explicitly defined in the product model (not a magic method like I assumed) that returns the value of `Mage::registry('current_category')`. So basically I registered and unregistered 'current_category' to meet my needs.

This still leaves my question partially unanswered though. I figured out how to hack around and get what URL I wanted, but technically the messy `/catalog/product/view/id/123/s/my-product-slug/`-type URLs still work and I'd rather all of the URL varieties route to the category-fied one. It would be great to be able to define a single, canonical URL style in Magento. If anyone has any further insight on this please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

To force that URL I'm pretty sure your product must include a category ID.

```
$product->setCategoryId(7)->getProductUrl();
```

Of course `7` is just an example. A product can belong to many categories so you'll have to decide how to pick one, perhaps by assuming the first.

```
list($categoryId,) = $product->getCategoryIds();
$product->setCategoryId($categoryId)->getProductUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't quite correct but it let me to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need and can't check right now but try this:

```
$product_url = "http://www.domain.com/".$product->getUrlPath();
```