# Magento getting a products rewritten URL

Tags: magento

If you look at this thread;
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/10807/

It adds a products rewritten url to the collection using;

> $collection->addUrlRewrite($categoryId);

I am not getting products this way, I am using this method to get an individual product:

> $product->load($productId);

After quite a bit of searching I cant seem to figure a way of getting a products rewritten url using this method, can anyone tell me how I may go about this please?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento consistent product URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466608/magento-consistent-product-urls)

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are looking for. `$product->getProductUrl()` - does it return product url in your needed format?

Comment: The product URL is correct to a point, unfortunately the product appears in multiple categories. The url is then made up of mydomain.com/category/sub-category/theproduct.html. So I need to get the various links in to the product.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not quite sure whether "rewritten url" means `request_path` or `target_path` in your question context, but anyway.

To get the request path of a single product you can do this:

```
$oProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
var_dump(
    $oProduct->getUrlPath()
);
```

To get the target path, you can use this:

```
$oProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$oRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath(
    $oProduct->getUrlPath()
);
var_dump(
    $oRewrite->getTargetPath()
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, almost what I am looking for, unfortunately its the products links in to it, that I need to get. The product can reside in more than one category, so I need to get all the links in for the product.