# Magento - Load product by url

Tags: magento

How would one load a product model in Magento, if the product id is not available and only the product's url is? For example, I want to retrieve the product model from it's friendly url, such as

```
electronics/cameras/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera.html
```

I found the following code in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560758/623854):

```
$oRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath(
    $path
);
```

but it doesn't seem to work correctly. The Magento documentation is very lacking in this area; does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution.

First use the URL rewrite model to find the route which matches your product:

```
    $vPath = 'electronics/cameras/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera.html';
    $oRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->loadByRequestPath($vPath);
```

Then you can call getProductId() on the route to locate the produc's id:

```
    $iProductId = $oRewrite->getProductId();
```

Finally if you require the product model object itself it's then a simple matter to call:

```
    $oProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($iProductId);
```

The main difference between the above, and the code example you've posted is the call to setStoreId.  The same product may have different URLs depending on which store it's in, so the routing component needs to have the appropriate store context before it can locate the product to display.

The advantages of this over Zachary Schuessler's solution is that using the URL rewriter will locate the correct product every time if the trailing portions of the url are the same for different products (e.g. folder1/my-product-name and folder2/my-product-name are different products).  Using the URL rewriter also works in situations where "folder1/my-product" refers to different products on different stores.  This may or may not apply to your environment.

Comment: Ah yes, it is very important to get the store id into the mix. Won't Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite') operate on the current store by default, without setting the store id explictly?

Comment: I did test that, and the natural assumption is that it would.  However, when I tried it, the url rewrite didn't find a product unless the store id was set explicitly.

Comment: Seems to be the solution I was looking for but I get no productID back, I get `NULL` instead. I'm using the code on the backend, so storeID is zero. Maybe something has changed? I do not want to create a new question as is exactly as the one asked here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious as to why you need to do this, since this might not be the best solution. This should be easy enough using the addAttributeToFilter() method on the collection:

```
$path = 'folder/folder/my-product-name';

// Get the product permalink
$productName = explode('/', $path);
$productName = end($productName);

// Filter the url_path with product permalink
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('url_path', $productName)
         ->getFirstItem();

Zend_Debug::dump($products->getData());exit;
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! I'm working on Netflix style additional info popups for products. Since Magento doesn't (by default) add any semantic information about the product (like id) into the rendered html, when making an ajax request all I have to query with is the product's url.

Comment: Finished using this method as I'm working on the backend and store is always `zero`